# VTK formatted output while each point lies at a new line

Tags: python, vtk

I aim to generate a .vtk format file with N **POINT** and M **POLYGON** data.
The formal output function is listed as below where `polymesh` represents the `vtk.vtkPolyData()` containing POINT and POLYGON

```
writer = vtk.vtkPolyDataWriter()
writer.SetFileTypeToASCII()
writer.SetInputData(polymesh)
writer.SetFileName(filename)
writer.Write()
```

**Here is my concern**
The output is shown as

```
...
POINTS N doubles
X0 Y0 Z0 X1 Y1 Z1 X2 Y2 Z2
X3 Y3 Z3 ...
...
POLYGONS
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8

9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

**Is there any solution that I could make each point shown at a new line and each polygon shown at a new line as well. For example, the expected output should be**

```
...
POINTS N doubles
X0 Y0 Z0
X1 Y1 Z1
X2 Y2 Z2
X3 Y3 Z3
...
POLYGONS
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option on the writer class.

I see only two solutions:

- create your own writer
- post process your file